# Next.js - Error: only absolute urls are supported

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js

I'm using express as my custom server for next.js. Everything is fine, when I click the products to the list of products

**Step 1**: I click the product Link

[image]

**Step 2**: It will show the products in the database.

[image]

However if I refresh the `/products` page, I will get this Error

[image]

Server code (Look at `/products` endpoint)

```
app.prepare()
.then(() => {
  const server = express()

  // This is the endpoints for products
  server.get('/api/products', (req, res, next) => {
    // Im using Mongoose to return the data from the database
    Product.find({}, (err, products) => {
      res.send(products)
    })
  })

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
  })
})
.catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

Pages - products.js (Simple layout that will loop the products json data)

```
import Layout from '../components/MyLayout.js'
import Link from 'next/link'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

const Products = (props) => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>List of Products</h1>
    <ul>
      { props.products.map((product) => (
        <li key={product._id}>{ product.title }</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </Layout>
)

Products.getInitialProps = async function() {

  const res = await fetch('/api/products')
  const data = await res.json()

  console.log(data)
  console.log(`Showed data fetched. Count ${data.length}`)

  return {
    products: data
  }
}

export default Products
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

As the error states, you will have to use an absolute URL for the `fetch` you're making. I'm assuming it has something to do with the different environments (client & server) on which your code can be executed. Relative URLs are just not explicit & reliable enough in this case.

One way to solve this would be to just hardcode the server address into your `fetch` request, another to set up a `config` module that reacts to your environment:

*/config/index.js*

```js
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

export const server = dev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : 'https://your_deployment.server.com';
```

*products.js*

```js
import { server } from '../config';

// ...

Products.getInitialProps = async function() {

  const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/products`)
  const data = await res.json()

  console.log(data)
  console.log(`Showed data fetched. Count ${data.length}`)

  return {
    products: data
  }
}
```

Comment: But how about when your data is really stored locally? I have a few localized static json's locally

Comment: @PaulT: `'undefined' === typeof window ? 'http://localhost:3000' : 'https://your_deployment.server.com';`

Answer (score 23):

Similar to the [@Shanker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62512796/5484841), but if you prefer not to install the additional package for this, here is how to do it.

```js
async getInitialProps({ req }) {
    const protocol = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || 'http'
    const baseUrl = req ? `${protocol}://${req.headers.host}` : ''

    const res = await fetch(baseUrl + '/api/products')
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to rely on HOST header? Headers are sent by client and can be anything. If a malicious code sends their server address in HOST they can get whatever data they want in your code.

It depends of course what do you do with that data later, but I do believe that it opens doors that are better to stay closed.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely not safe to rely on headers as it can be altered by man-in-the-middle attack.

Answer (score 13):

It sounds silly but worth mentioning. If you're using SSR in your webapp the fetch call will work with a relative link on the client but will fail on the server. Only the server needs an absolute link!

If you want to prevent the server from making the request just wrap it in logic

```
if(global.window){
   const req = fetch('/api/test');
   ...
}
```

Comment: This does not work if you wanna prefetch data on server side

Answer (score 6):

This simple solution worked for me without having to add an additional config file,

Install

```
npm install --save next-absolute-url
```

Usage

```
import absoluteUrl from "next-absolute-url";

async getInitialProps({ req }){
  const { origin } = absoluteUrl(req, req.headers.host);
  console.log('Requested URL ->',origin); 
  // (or) other way
  const host = absoluteUrl(req, req.headers.host);
  console.log('Requested URL ->',host.origin); 
}
```

Comment: `req` will only be available on serverside, so you will need to add some checks/handling for the clientside rendering

Answer (score 5):

You could utilize environment variables if your project is hosted on a provider that supports it.

env.local

```
// Local
URL="http://localhost:3000"

// Production
URL="https://prod.com"
```

Then you can use the following.

```
const { URL } = process.env;
const data = await fetcher(URL + '/api');
```

Comment: This would still raise the error.

Comment: can you actually destructure process.env?

Comment: @ChukwuemekaMaduekwe yes. just like any object

Answer (score 4):

In the NextJS 9.5, we can also use `process.cwd()`. 
process.cwd() will give you the directory where Next.js is being executed.

```
import path from 'path'
import fs from "fs";

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    const dataFilePath = path.join(process.cwd(), "jsonFiles", "data.json");
    console.log(dataFilePath);     // will be YourProject/jsonFiles/data.json

    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(dataFilePath, "utf8");
    const data: TypeOfData[] = JSON.parse(fileContents);
    return { props: { data } };
};
```

Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#reading-files-use-processcwd

Answer (score 3):

Case 1. It's not an error. The isomorphic-unfetch is running by SSR mode, so Node.js needs to know the absolute url to fetch from it, because the back-end doesn't know your browser settings.

Case 2. Another scenario is to prevent the http host poisoning headers attack.

> append secret keys and tokens to links containing it:

```
<a href="http://_SERVER['HOST']?token=topsecret">  (Django, Gallery, others)
```

> ....and even directly import scripts from it:

```
<script src="http://_SERVER['HOST']/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4">
```

Case 3. The `isomorphic-unfetch` it's the library we are going to use to fetch data. It's a simple implementation of the browser fetch API, but works both in client and server environments.

#### Read more about it:

1. [Isomorphic unfetch - Switches between unfetch & node-fetch for client & server](https://github.com/developit/unfetch/tree/master/packages/isomorphic-unfetch)
2. [Prevent http host headers attack](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/1213#issuecomment-281187610)
3. [Fetching Data for Pages](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages/fetching-batman-shows)

Answer (score 2):

Putting this out there because this showed up in google results for my problem, even though the question itself isn't really related (outside of the fact that the same dependency is throwing the same error message, albeit in a different context for a different reason).

I got this issue from using hardhat while attempting to verify (`verify:verify`) my contract on etherscan. The problem was that in the hardhat config, I didn't have a full `url` under `rinkeby` (since I was verifying on rinkeby, would be mainnet, etc.). Copy/pasting some config stuff quickly into a project I cloned from someone else, they had a full URL in their `.env`, while I had the url in the config and stored only my api key in my `.env`.

To figure this out, though, was straightforward--go into `node_modules`, then find the `node-fetch` folder, then `lib`, (this is from memory--just find the line that is vomitting in your stack trace) then the line number, and put a console log there to see what the "bad" url you're seeing is. Usually that's enough of a clue; in my case, it was an API key, obviously not a URL, and that made it straightforward to solve.

Answer (score 2):

## Make sure what the *value* of your API url is

In my case, I was using `POST` but my `url` was somewhat `undefined`.

Use `console.log` to see where is your request going.

Answer (score 1):

this is a way to get the base hostname to fetch data from external endpoint
without getting that error

```
function return_url(context) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    return `https://${context.req.rawHeaders[1]}`;
  } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    return "http://localhost:3000";
  }
}
```

and on the getServerSideProps or getStaticProps functions you use

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  let url = return_url(context);
  const data = await fetch(`${url}/yourEndPoint`).then((res) => res.json());
  return {
    props: {
      data: data,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `absolute` path issues. Try to use [swr](https://swr.vercel.app/#overview) to access data.

Notice: This is a React hooks so you must call inside the component.

```js
import useSWR from 'swr';

// optionally you can use unfetch package from npm or built yours to handle promise.
const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json())

export const AllProducts = () => {
  const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/products', fetcher)
  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>
  
  return (
    <div>{data}</div>
  );
};
```

#### Export or deploying in production

Whenever you are trying to deploy on Vercel you might encounter an error. For instance `

```
warn - Statically exporting a Next.js application via `next export` disables API routes`.
```

It means you are trying to export data and `NextJS` does not support fetching data from `pages/api/*` directory. To avoid errors, its better to separate build and export command.

```
// package.json

{
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",   // No next export command
    "start": "next start"
  },
}
```

Thanks folks for great contribution and I hope the answer shared will help somebody too.

Answer (score 0):

### Nextjs 13

In my case error occured only on build. The case was that I had .env.developmet only. I had to aslo create **.env** file.

Answer (score 0):

If accepted answer does not work please check the following:

- If your env variables are defined in Vercel like they should
- If they are, make not defined them
- Make sure to redeploy as those env are resolved during build time

Answer (score -1):

If you are using next environment config prefix your variables with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` as mentioned here [Exposing Environment Variables to the Browser](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser).

Answer (score -2):

USE: NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL="http://localhost:1337" instead of

NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL=http://localhost:1337

Answer (score -13):

use .log(console.log) after nock , so you will get exact unmatched and expected url .
Example:

```
     nock("http://localhost")
.log(console.log)
.persist()
.get("/api/config")
.reply(200, { data: 1234 })
```