# Next.JS: Can't call Internal API in getInitialProps. Got Error: read ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js

When I use internal API route in getInitialProps I get this error.

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:620:25)

static async getInitialProps({ reduxStore }) {
    const res = await Axios.get("/api/recent/1");
    await reduxStore.dispatch({ type: LIST, payload: res.data });
    return { }
}
```

But If I use external API server, it works fine.

```
static async getInitialProps({ reduxStore }) {
    const res = await Axios.get("http://abc.herokuapp.com/api/recent/1");
    await reduxStore.dispatch({ type: LIST, payload: res.data });
    return { }
}
```

If I call API in componentDidMount, it works fine in both cases, but in getinitialProps I couldn't handle internal API which are on my Express server.

Please help! Is there a problem in my code? I am searching from past couple of hours but couldn't solve it.

Comment: URLs in getInitialProps must be absolute, since they are ran from the server. You must include the hostname in the path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Next.js - Error: only absolute urls are supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342226/next-js-error-only-absolute-urls-are-supported)

Comment: did you find any solution??

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `baseUrl` from the request.

```
async getInitialProps({ req }) {
    const protocol = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || 'http'
    const baseUrl = req ? `${protocol}://${req.headers.host}` : ''

    const res = await fetch(baseUrl + '/api/recent/1')
    ...
}
```