# Vercel TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel

I tried to deploy my next.js app to Vercel all day. The app works well in dev mode and I can build as well on my machine, but it fails when I deploy to Vercel.
I tried all the variations I could find without success. This is how it looks right now:

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
export const server = dev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : `https://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}`;

export async function getStaticProps(): Promise<{ props: ProjectsProps }> {
  const response = await fetch(`${server}/api/github`);
  const { stars, repos, followers } = await response.json();

  return { props: { stars, repos, followers, revalidate: 600 } };
}
export default Projects;
```

and the error I get:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question: [nextjs error when build production for static website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66206394/1870780)? You should not use `fetch()` to call an internal API route in `getStaticProps`. Directly import the logic used inside your API route instead.

Comment: Took me some time, but I solved the issue with the answer you provided! Thank you!