# Vercel Next.js build error of simple Next.js code

Tags: deployment, next.js, vercel

I created a simple Next.js code that runs fine locally, but has errors during deployment on Vercel:

1. Use npx create-next-app to create a new Next.js application. Current version is 11.1.0
2. In  pages/index.js add getStaticProps function that gets data from pages/api/hello (the default file created by create-next-app)

   import { API_URL } from 'config';
   ...
   export const getStaticProps = async () => {
   const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/hello`);
   const data = await res.json();

   return {
   props: {
   data,
   revalidate: 1,
   },
   };
   };
3. Under the root create config/index.js and write there

   export const API_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL || 'http://localhost:3000';
4. Full version is available on  https://github.com/RayaLevinson/next_js_test
5. Locally (using npm run dev) works fine.
6. Deploy on Vercel.7. Build error appears:
   Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

   TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported

   ```
    at getNodeRequestOptions (/vercel/path0/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1305:9)

    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1410:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)

    at Function.fetch [as default] (/vercel/path0/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1407:9)
    at fetchWithAgent (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/node-polyfill-fetch.js:38:39)
   ```

   at getStaticProps (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:60:21)
   at renderToHTML (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:329:30)
   at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js:273:36
   at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [Fetch error when building Next.js static website in production](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66206394/1870780)? Essentially, you should _not_ fetch from an internal API route in `getStaticProps`. Instead, directly import the logic used inside your API route.

Comment: Thank you! Full answer is here: [https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#write-server-side-code-directl](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#write-server-side-code-directly)