# What is the best approach to build a NextJS app with a separate NodeJS back-end

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm trying to build a `NextJS` app and I have separate `NodeJS` backend but I have some doubts about the approach that I could follow. For an example let's take login scenario and I'm explaining below the way I can implement it.

**1st approach**

- I define my interface in `/pages/signin.tsx` and inside of the
  `onSubmit` function I make an API call to my hosted backend and
  getting data.

**2nd approach**

- I define the API call to my hosted backend inside `/pages/api/signin.tsx`
- Then I define my interface in `/pages/signin.tsx` and inside of the
  `onSubmit` function I call the `NextJS` inbuilt API that I defined inside `/pages/api/signin.tsx` and through that calling my backend.

Should I use NextJS server for every API call or should I use the old way of calling API's in react.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why use Next.js API route with an external API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69536148/1870780)? You don't have to use Next.js API routes to proxy the requests unless you have a reason for it.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. Thanks