# Handling API requests in the NEXT13 application [API Route vs custom hook]

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js, next.js13

I need an answer to a question about handling requests to e.g. an external API. And more specifically about how to perform them best and which way to use depending on the situation.

Let me give a simple example.
I need to execute a POST method on one of the endpoints that will pass an object containing a first name, last name and nickname.

Which approach should I use.

1. Create a classic custom hook, which I then use in a specific component or page?
2. Use the api folder and handle request there?
3. Make this request directly on the page where I have the sample form

Is there any difference in using either of these solutions? Should any of these approaches be used in a particular case?

Or when to use a particular approach?

What if I need to specify a specific ID that is forwarded dynamically by routing?

The official documentation does not quite answer this question directly.

Comment: The approach of creating an API to interact with your backend is most definitely encouraged as it obfuscates not only the location of your backend but also the shape of data received/sent.

Comment: Also check this slightly related question: [Why use Next.js API route with an external API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69536148/1870780).