# Nextjs cannot find internal api link

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I cannot use internal path to fetch my internal api data
The error said

```
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/hello**
------------
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const data = await fetch("/api/hello"
  ...
------------
```

But it works, if I use full url (hard code) like this

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const data = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/hello"
  ...
```

Anyone know how to use internal path instead of full url?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling an internal API route from inside `getStaticProps`, simply use the logic from the API route directly in `getStaticProps`. See [Fetch error when building Next.js static website in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66202840/fetch-error-when-building-next-js-static-website-in-production).

Comment: Thanks for this comment, now the app Im working is working now. tsk tsk

Answer (score 3):

When I do this, I get

```
TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
```

So absolute URLs are required.

You can to simplify this with an environment variable

```
BASE_FETCH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

and then call fetch with

```js
const data = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_FETCH_URL}api/hello`);
```

See https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-lamport-z252dl?file=/pages/index.js (might break in the future if the url of the temporary deployment changes)