# Why do I need to put http://localhost:3000 for fetching from API routes in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I made an API route in the pages folder on a NextJS project. It works fine, I can fetch data from it by going to the URL directly such as http://localhost:3000/api/tv/popular. I want to fetch the data in getStaticProps and then forward to the components. It works fine if I do it this way

```js
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (ctx) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/tv/popular");

  return {
    props: {
      popularContent: data,
    },
  };
};
```

**But** if I remove local host and send request to `axios.get("/api/tv/popular")` it fails.

Why is this, I thought this should be possible in NextJs to not include localhost

Comment: You should not call an internal API route inside `getStaticProps`. Instead, you can use your API logic directly in `getStaticProps`. See [Fetch error when building Next.js static website in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66202840/fetch-error-when-building-next-js-static-website-in-production).

Comment: Whaaa, I have been doing that, and its been working for me so far. So what I've been doing is that in the API routes, I fetch data from a database, and external APIs, then reshape the data to fit my use case and then send that as a response. Afterwards, ill go to my page and just do one single fetch to routes in API folder with `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`. Somehow I felt like this kept the code clean and somewhat separated me from having to look at backend code and front-end code in the same file. I don't seem to have any of the problems mentioned in this other post

Comment: Try building the app and running it in production mode (`next build && next start`). You can still separate the backend logic into different files if you so wish.

Comment: It seems to be working without any issue, I checked the logs, [link](https://watched-this.vercel.app/) but basically what you're saying is that its wrong practice to call the internal API from `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`

Answer (score 4):

As per API concept, it has to come from a server correct?
Hence Nextjs gives the same server where it runs. Hence you have to use localhost:3000 or any port you give

In future it will be a problem for you while production.
Hence use .env file

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL = http://localhost:3000
```

and use it in your api calls whenever you go for production you can change the same.

Hope it clarifies something.

Comment: ah smart, thanks, man. I thought NextJS automatically detects the URL part before /api cause the same server is being used for front and back