# getStaticProps needs complete url and I cant provide url when building on vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm trying to host a Next.js project using vercel and some api calls in getStaticProps() uses api folder inside next.js pages folder. and this function also needs a full url so I can't provide only `/api/get-products`. insted I have to provide something like `http:localhost:3000/api/get-products`.

[image: getStaticProps() call]

[image: URL here]

[image: this is the URL that needs to change]

What should I do to make this build successfully on vercel. because if I run `npm run build`. It builds sucessfully.

this is the error i'm getting on Vercel

[image: error]

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: You should not call an internal API route inside `getStaticProps`. Instead, use your API logic directly in `getStaticProps`. See [Fetch error when building Next.js static website in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66202840/fetch-error-when-building-next-js-static-website-in-production).

Answer (score 0):

I believe on the 3rd image you show us the content of the .env file in your IDE.
Most probably, you have not defined such an env variable in Vercel. Here you can find info about that: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables

Looking at the error, I'd assume you have committed the .env file with exactly the same value as on the image. Hence if you haven't redefined the variable in Vercel, it is taken from the .env file from your codebase.

Comment: I tried that. even when I add the environment variables there. same error comes. problem is How to point same url ?

Comment: In your .env file set 
NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL=${VERCEL_URL}
This should do the thing.
And for local development create .env.local with
NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL=http://localhost:3000