# Deploying NextJS in Vercel Failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, deployment

Hi I'm beginner in web development. I'm trying to deploy my first NextJS app in Vercel but I always get this error.

**Error:**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6662:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6636:27)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1236:60
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /download/[appName]
    at /vercel/path0/Bulaloi App/next-app/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1158:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

**Download page:**

```
import DownloadPage from '../../components/DownloadPageComponents/DownloadPage.js'

export default function DownloadPagee({ data }) {
  return <DownloadPage data={data} />;
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { appName } = params;

  // Fetch data from `/api/download/${appName}`
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/api/download/${appName}`);
  const data = await res.json();

  return { props: { data } };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Fetch data from `/api/apps-games/all`
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/api/apps-games/all`);
  const data = await res.json();

  // Map each object's `appName` property to `params`
  const paths = data.map((obj) => ({
    params: { appName: obj.appName },
  }));

  return { paths, fallback: false };
}
```

**The .env variable**

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_URL="https://bulaloi.vercel.app"
```

I have tried changing the .env variable into `NEXT_PUBLIC_URL="http://bulaloi.vercel.app"` but error stays the same. I'm very new to this SSG so I think the problem might be in download page code, please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add environment variables to the vercel. when you click on the project, you will have this menu:

[image]

Comment: I have tried it but it still gives the same error. The local development doesn't have problem though.

Comment: Did u put right name

Comment: Yes I did. I think this answer might just fix my problem ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/66206394/17085102 ), since I'm fetching from my internal api routes in getStaticProps and getStaticPaths but I will try it tommorow. Thanks btw