# Project deployment with next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have a question about a project deployment with NextJS/Vercel.

According to documentation, `await fetch` is supporting only absolute URLs. Example:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const route = process.env.APIpath + 'api/category/getCategories';
  const res = await fetch(route)
  const json = await res.json()
  return {
    props: {
      data: json,
      },
  };
}
```

where `APIpath: 'http://localhost:3000/',`

Question: How can I deploy a project on `vercel.com/test/my_project`? because when I only change `process.env.APIpath` to `vercel.com/test/my_project` = error.

P.S. Error message
Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
categories/database/categoryList - the page I am calling `getStaticProps(context)` above

Comment: How about your error message?

Comment: You cannot fetch your own API routes during static build. See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16068

Comment: Added error to question body

Comment: you shouldn't fetch your own api routes from the server which is why this is happening. It's supposed to be used from the client What you can do, however, is make async functions in the lib directory for example that rival your api route functions 

Partition your asynchronous logic between several environments

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [Internal API fetch with getServerSideProps? (Next.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65760948/1870780)? It mentions `getServerSideProps` but the same applies to `getStaticProps`.

Comment: I can't use fetch as it needs absolute path, trying to do with useSWR