# Next.js session is not available on the server side when calling a function inside getServerSideProps

Tags: node.js, session, next.js, session-cookies, session-state

I was wondering if it would be possible to call my API from the getServerSideProps like:

```
await axios.post('/api/auth/refresh-token');
```

and use previously set user cookies on the server-side.

Right now, whenever I do that, the server thinks it's a different session and cookies are not available.

I use next-iron-session and if I call the API on the client-side everything is fine and session is available.

Comment: Do not call an internal API from `getServerSideProps`: [Internal API fetch with getServerSideProps? (Next.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752932/internal-api-fetch-with-getserversideprops-next-js/65760948#65760948). You can access the cookies in `getServerSideProps` through the context object `ctx.req.cookies`.