# Fetching local and production on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, deployment, fetch, next.js, vercel

I have a really serious question I didn't find the answer about Vercel (NextJS).

I am trying to deploy the project on Versel and I am using some structures to get data from API, example:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const route = process.env.APIpath + 'api/category/getCategories'; //focusing here, ok on localhost
  const res = await fetch(route)
  const json = await res.json()
  return {
    props: {
      data: json,
      },
  };
}
```

As `fetch` is using only **absolute URL path**, I need to define base url with variable `process.env.APIpath`.

With local testing I have `process.env.APIpath = 'http://localhost:3000/'` **but**: I need to define a production variable for Vercel deployment and *I am using serverless functions*.

Some info about Vercel, according to this [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching), we can actually `fetch` the data. But during the deployment process, I always have errors on the pages where I am calling `fetch`, for example:

```
//this code triggers an error as code shown above, ok on localhost
const res = await fetch(process.env.APIpath + 'api/category/getCategory?_id='+ pid, {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)
})
```

I am getting errors because of `fetch`. Of course, I understand that during the deployment Vercel can't build the production version as I am using "hardcoded" `process.env.APIpath`.

How can I define clearly the `process.env.APIpath` (or any different built variables) to deploy the project? Please, note that every time Versel generates generic project link as `nextjs-fhp5exsvo-testing.vercel.app`.

P.S. Will be happy for any help, having an issue with deployment for about 5 days already.

Comment: Is this a CRA or Next.js app?

Comment: Next js app. ( will add some info to post now)

Comment: You should not make calls to internal API routes in `getStaticProps`. Instead, directly import the logic used inside your API route: [Internal API fetch with getServerSideProps? (Next.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752932/internal-api-fetch-with-getserversideprops-next-js/65760948#65760948) (mentions `getServerSideProps` but same applies to `getStaticProps`).

Comment: Thanks, but you comment is inscruding fetch I can't really use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I partially solved my issue

Instead of using `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps` to fetch data from API, I am using `useSWR` library. This solution seems to be good with `local` and `production` versions.

**1.Change to `useSWR` instead of `getStaticProps`**

not working code with getStaticProps

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const route = process.env.APIpath + 'api/category/getCategories'; 
  const res = await fetch(route)
  const json = await res.json()
  return {
    props: {
      data: json,
      },
  };
}
```

changed to `useSWR`, working example for `local`, `test`, and `production`

```
import useSWR from 'swr'
import React from 'react';

//important to return only result, not Promise
const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

const Categories = () => {
 //getting data and error
 const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/category/getCategories', fetcher)
 if (error) return <div>Failed to load</div>
 if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>
 if (data){
   // {data} is completed, it's ok!
   //your code here to make something with {data}
   return (
      <div>
      //something here, example {data.name}
      </div>
   )
 }
}

export default Categories
```

Notice: I am not sure that `useSWR` will work perfectly with `SEO`, but according to this [link](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs), we can even use it with `SSR`.

**2.Modifying MongoDB settings.**

As I am using `mongoDB`, you need to `check MongoDB settings` properly. Once u did it, you need to `check your API routes` (not pages) are in `/pages/api/[apiname].js`. Only after API routes work (on Vercel) I suggest you start coding your local version.

**3.Change your `deployment variables` on Vercel.**

You need to configure environment variables and some others on Vercel. [More details here](https://vercel.com/docs/environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You can `fetch` data from an api route using a relative path with Next.js.

Straight from [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side):

```js
function Profile() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    fetch('api/profile-data')  // <-- relative path
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data)
        setLoading(false)
      })
  }, [])

  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>
  if (!profileData) return <p>No profile data</p>

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
      <p>{data.bio}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Next.js docs do also explicitly recommend using SWR, like @ChilTest's answer suggests.  That said, the relative path is not a special SWR-only feature.