# `Only absolute URLs are supported` error while trying to deploy a Next.js app

Tags: next.js, vercel

I encountered a `TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported` error while tying to deploy a Next.js app both in `Vercel` and `Netlify`. In my app, I have a `config` file to avoid of `absolute path` errors, since data is fetched from the server. 
`config.js`

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

export const server = dev
  ? "http://localhost:3000"
  : "https://next-js-next-app-pjjs4ka8d-grf.vercel.app";
```

The domain I picked from `vercel` when a random domain was generated before starting the deployment.
But I guess it's wrong and I must provide another url for deployment.

Here is how I am using the `server` url in the app from `config` file
in `pages/article[id]` file.

```
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/articles/${context.params.id}`);
  const article = await res.json();
  return {
    props: {
      article,
    },
  };
};

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/articles/`);

  const articles = await res.json();
  const ids = articles.map((article) => article.id);

  const paths = ids.map((id) => ({ params: { id: id.toString() } }));

  return {
    fallback: "blocking",
    paths: paths,
  };
};
```

Error output in `Vercel` while trying to deploy

```
10:11:04.813    > Build error occurred
10:11:04.815    TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
10:11:04.815        at getNodeRequestOptions (/vercel/path0/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1305:9)
10:11:04.815        at /vercel/path0/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1410:19
10:11:04.815        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
10:11:04.815        at fetch (/vercel/path0/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1407:9)
10:11:04.815        at getStaticPaths (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/article/[id].js:168:21)
10:11:04.815        at buildStaticPaths (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:16:86)
10:11:04.815        at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:26:628
10:11:04.815        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
10:11:04.815        at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584) {
10:11:04.815      type: 'TypeError'
10:11:04.815    }
10:11:04.834    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
10:11:04.834    npm ERR! errno 1
10:11:04.838    npm ERR! traversytutorial@0.1.0 build: `next build && next export`
10:11:04.838    npm ERR! Exit status 1
10:11:04.839    npm ERR! 
10:11:04.839    npm ERR! Failed at the traversytutorial@0.1.0 build script.
10:11:04.839    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
10:11:04.846    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
10:11:04.847    npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2021-06-18T08_11_04_839Z-debug.log
10:11:04.859    Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you importing the config file correctly? Could you add that import part of the code too?

Comment: Hi @BojanKrkic thanks for response. 
Sure, Here it is: import { server } from "../config";
Actually, the app works fine locally. Problems I have only on deployment

Comment: Just shooting in the dark - could the issue be that it's looking for `config/index.js` when you do `import {server} from "../config"`? Try renaming `config.js` to `index.js`, worth a shot...

Comment: Hi @juliomalves thanks for the answer. I updated my question with the code from `pages/article/[id].js`.  But I think I am doing pretty much the same here.

Comment: @Gregfan You should use the logic that's in your API routes directly in `getStaticPaths`/`getStaticProps` rather than fetching from your internal API. See [Internal API fetch with getServerSideProps? (Next.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65760948/1870780) for more details (mentions `getServerSideProps` but same applies here).

Comment: Hi @juliomalves thanks for the quick response. 
Does it mean that I need to import the 'handler function'  from 'api' to `pages/article/[id]` file and use in `getStaticPaths/getStaticProps` files instead of fetching from internal API?

Comment: Not the full handler as you don't want the part that deals with returning the response - just the logic to get the data you need (like the example in that answer I've linked).

Comment: @juliomalves ok, thanks, I'll try it