# npm run build error , unable to run build command in next.js

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

i am trying to run npm run build but i always get an error .even though all the pages are working fine and no errors . I  have added code for api calls using getServerSidePorps .

****error:****

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  type: 'Error',
  config: {
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/admin/user/users/list',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.4'
    },
    transformRequest: [ null ],
    transformResponse: [ null ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    }
  },
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED'
}
```

API CALLS

```
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const additionalData = {
    InitialSkip: 0,
    initialLimit: 3,
  };
  const response = await axios.post(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/admin/user/users/list",
    additionalData,
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  );

  return {
    props: {
      data: response.data,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Please provide more information. When does this error appear? What does your package.josn npm build look like, etc.

Comment: @wuno after i run npm run build in next application after 20 ,30 sec i get this error. this message shows url on which i send axios request

Comment: @wuno what information should i share , kindly help me out

Comment: Are you making an API call in the pages directory and inside of getStaticPaths or getStaticProps?

Comment: @wuno yes exactly  , i have added code kindly check please

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Internal API fetch with getServerSideProps? (Next.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65760948/1870780)? Use the logic that's in your API route directly in `getServerSideProps`.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem -**

npm build fails with connection error.

**Answer -**

You should not `fetch()` to an API route in `getServerSideProps()`.

> Note: You should not use fetch() to call an API route in
> getServerSideProps. Instead, directly import the logic used inside
> your API route. You may need to slightly refactor your code for this
> approach.
>
> Fetching from an external API is fine!

[Check this link for more info -](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#write-server-side-code-directly)

The issue here is that you are calling the API route and not an external API.