# Server Error Error: Request failed with status code 500

Tags: next.js

```
 export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/products');
      return {
        props: {
          kebabList: res.data
        }
      }
    };




    // get all the products
  if (method === "GET") {
    try {
      const products = await Product.find();
      res.status(200).json(products);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  }
```

**When I first load the app it is showing this error**
*Server Error
Error: Request failed with status code 500*

**If I reload again then it works fine but after deploying on vercel the error is permanent**

Comment: Is `/api/products` an internal API route? If so, you shouldn't be fetching data from it inside `getServerSideProps`. You should move the logic that's in the API route into `getServerSideProps` instead. See [Internal API fetch with getServerSideProps? (Next.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752932/internal-api-fetch-with-getserversideprops-next-js).

Answer (score 1):

When you have deployed your app on vercel, your API url might be changed `http://localhost:3000` to `http://your-domain(live-url).com`.

```
    export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get('http://your-domain(live-url).com/api/products'); //  please focus on this line. I belive you have messed up here
      return {
        props: {
          kebabList: res.data
        }
      }
    };

    // get all the products
  if (method === "GET") {
    try {
      const products = await Product.find();
      res.status(200).json(products);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  }
```