# Getting 500 Internal Server Error (using axios). Locally it gives error axiosError but it works fine when I hit refresh & everything loads

Tags: node.js, axios, next.js, web-deployment

I deployed my next app on this url 
https://nthing.vercel.app/
It is working fine locally although it gives error `AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500`
 But when I hit refresh my api runs and everything works properly. I added .env vars also but don't know what is going wrong.

[GET] /  /* I got following error in vercel function */

```
rmResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.27.2'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/products',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      constructed: true,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError],
      socket: [Function: handleRequestSocket]
    },
    _eventsCount: 3,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      protocol: 'http:',
      path: '/api/products',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: 'localhost',
      port: '3000',
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/api/products'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: true,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'GET /api/products HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.27.2\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost:3000\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/api/products',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    _currentUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/products',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  page: '/'
}
RequestId: ce11ff47-40ab-4c50-9e90-9c118179bce6 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

../api/products/index.js

```
import dbConnect from "../../../util/mongo";
import Product from "../../../models/Product";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { method, cookies } = req;

  const token = cookies.token;

  dbConnect();

  if (method === "GET") {
    try {
      const products = await Product.find();
      res.status(200).json(products);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  }

  if (method === "POST") {
    if (!token || token !== process.env.token) {
      return res.status(401).json("Not authenticated!");
    }
    try {
      const product = await Product.create(req.body);
      res.status(201).json(product);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  }
}
```

My main index.js page

```
import axios from "axios";
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useState } from "react";
import Add from "../components/Add";
import AddButton from "../components/AddButton";
import Featured from "../components/Featured";
import ServiceList from "../components/ServiceList";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

export default function Home({ serviceList, admin }) {
  const [close, setClose] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>On-Demand Home Service</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Best service on you doorsteps" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Featured />
      {<AddButton setClose={setClose} />}
      <ServiceList serviceList={serviceList} />
      {!close && <Add setClose={setClose} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  const myCookie = ctx.req?.cookies || "";
  let admin = false;

  if (myCookie.token === process.env.TOKEN) {
    admin = true;
  }

  const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/products");
  return {
    props: {
      serviceList: res.data,
      admin,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [Internal API fetch with getServerSideProps? (Next.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752932/internal-api-fetch-with-getserversideprops-next-js)? You shouldn't be calling your internal API in `getServerSideProps`, instead you want to use the logic that's in your API route directly.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can fetch from your internal API in getServerSideProps, though you could also import and call your API logic directly. It's getStaticProps where you have to always call your API logic directly. Reference: https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/api-routes/api-routes-details