# Nextjs: "Error: Task timed out after 10.02 seconds" netlify and vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My page import some module:
[image: import module]
In getServerSideProps I get query and call api, then return response.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  try {
    var startTime = Date.now();
    const query = context.query;
    const url = `myurl with query`;
    const searchResulf = await axios.get(url);
    var endTime = Date.now();
    console.log(`Took ${endTime - startTime} milliseconds`);
    return {
      props: {
        searchResulf: searchResulf.data,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) { 
    console.error("error"); 
    return {
      props: {
      searchResulf: null,
    },
  }; 
}};
```

In localhost everything is fine, never more than 2s waiting for api.

```
Took 939 milliseconds
Took 415 milliseconds
Took 840 milliseconds
```

In brower, never more than 5s for file HTML:
[image]

But when deploying on netlify (and vercel) this page is broken, other sites work properly. The function log get nothing, just "Error: Task timed out after 10.02 seconds".

I'm new to Nextjs, this is my first project, I'm stuck here for 2 days because of this error.

Comment: Is the URL internal (to an internal Next.js API route) or an external API endpoint?

Comment: It's API route. I've a console.log under getServerSideProps() before even the try-catch. But funcion log nothing, maybe getServerSideProps not working yet.

Comment: You shouldn't call internal API routes inside `getServerSideProps`, instead use the API logic directly. See [Internal API fetch with getServerSideProps? (Next.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752932/internal-api-fetch-with-getserversideprops-next-js).