# Next js with Mongodb, mongoose, and vercel deployment gives 500 error(works fine on localhost)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, vercel, http-status-code-500

I am trying to deploy my next js app that uses mongodb and mongoose.  Everything works fine on localhost however when I deploy to vercel I'm getting this error from the logs:

[image: error logs]

I have double-checked my environment variables and everything seems fine with them.

Here is my mongo connection:
[image: mongo connection]

Here are the pages that bring in data using getServerSideProps:

[image: index page]

[image: tours page]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Also, you should not call internal API routes from inside `getServerSideProps`, use the API route logic directly instead. See [Internal API fetch with getServerSideProps? (Next.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752932/internal-api-fetch-with-getserversideprops-next-js).

Answer (score 0):

Try to make mongo DB queries inside the getServerSideProps function. It is mentioned in the NextJS [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props).

And try to build locally first.
Make sure to change the ENV files on the vercel before building.