# NextJS getServerSideProps() fetch multiple endpoints at once in delay

Tags: javascript, async-await, next.js, es6-promise, fetch-api

Is there a way to fetch data from multiple API routes in a single getServerSideProps() in delay?

I encountered an 429 error(too many requests) when I was trying to fetch data from multiple endpoints at once with `Promise.all()`.

Is there any method that I can use to fetch the multiple array endpoints in 1 second delay each?

```
async function getClients () {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/clients')
  const json = await res.json()
  return Object.entries(json)
}

async function getDetails (clients) {
  const details = await Promise.all(
    clients.map(async (item) => {
      const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/clients/' + item.clientId;
      const res = await fetch(url)
      const json = await res.json()
      return json
    })
  )
  return details
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const clients = await getClients()
  const details = await getDetails(clients)

  return {
    props: {
      clients,
      details,
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the `http://localhost:3000/api/clients` endpoint pointing to an internal API route? If so, you should avoid doing so. See [Internal API fetch with getServerSideProps? (Next.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752932/internal-api-fetch-with-getserversideprops-next-js). That will avoid the API requests altogether and most likely solve the issue.

Comment: @juliomalves It's pointing to an external API route. The endpoint above for example purposes only. And thanks for your advice, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the rate limiter that's part of the [async-sema](https://github.com/vercel/async-sema) package.

It's also worth noting that you should avoid calling your Nextjs API routes from your `getServerSideProps` function. As it's already running on the server you can perform whatever logic is inside your API routes directly and avoid the penalty of an extra network hop.

```js
import { RateLimit } from "async-sema";

async function getClients () {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/clients')
  const json = await res.json()
  return Object.entries(json)
}

async function getDetails (clients) {
  const lim = RateLimit(5);
  const details = await Promise.all(
    clients.map(async (item) => {
      await lim();
      const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/clients/' + item.clientId;
      const res = await fetch(url)
      const json = await res.json()
      return json
    })
  )
  return details
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const clients = await getClients()
  const details = await getDetails(clients)

  return {
    props: {
      clients,
      details,
    },
  }
}
```