# nextAuth unstable_getsession and getToken returning null not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

when i use useSession in my front next app everything is okey i can get the user loged in but when i try to use getToken or unstable_getSession in my api it always returns null

im trying to use unstable_getsession to check if a user is loged in to be able to perform a GET request on users

my  [...nextauth].ts :

```js
/* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */
import bcrypt from "bcrypt"
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import Users from "../../../../models/user"
import connectDB from "../../../../utils/connectDB"

connectDB()
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            id: "credentials",

            name: "my-project",

            credentials: {
                email: {
                    label: "email",
                    type: "email",
                    placeholder: "jsmith@example.com",
                },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
            },
            async authorize(credentials: any) {
                const { email, password } = credentials

                const user = await Users.findOne({ email })
                if (!user) throw new Error("Incorrect password or email.")

                const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password as string)
                if (!isMatch) throw new Error("Incorrect password or email.")

                return user.toObject()
            },
        }),
    ],
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    pages: {
        signIn: "/auth/signin",
    },
    callbacks: {
        jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
            user && (token.user = user)
            return token
        },
        session: async ({ session, token }) => {
            session.user = token.user as any
            return session
        },
    },
    session: { strategy: "jwt" },
    theme: {
        colorScheme: "auto", // "auto" | "dark" | "light"
        brandColor: "", // Hex color code #33FF5D
        logo: "/vercel.svg", // Absolute URL to image
    },
    // Enable debug messages
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
}
export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

my api route api/users/index.ts:

```js
import { unstable_getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
import { Session } from "next-auth"
import { authOptions } from "../auth/[...nextauth]"

export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse
) {
    const { method } = req
    
    const session = (await unstable_getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)) as Session
    console.log(session) // this return null even if im loged in

    ....
```

Comment: i think i figured out im using my get all users route in getServerSideProps and since it running in server before nextauth runs it return null correct me if im wrong

Comment: You shouldn't be calling an internal API route from inside `getServerSideProps`. Simply use the logic that is in the API route directly in `getServerSideProps`. See [Internal API fetch with getServerSideProps? (Next.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752932/internal-api-fetch-with-getserversideprops-next-js).

Comment: that what i did thanks you