# Nextjs failing on getServerSideProps for no reason

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am learning NextJS .. I have an API (in Laravel) that has an endpoint `/api/user` which is protected with a token and just returns a very simple user object as below;

```php
{
    "data": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Testing User",
        "email": "testing@mctestface.com",
        "updated_at": "2022-08-23T10:39:32.000000Z",
        "created_at": "2022-08-23T10:39:32.000000Z"
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a `user settings` page in NextJS ... I am hitting the user endpoint, with the token which is stored as a cookie, if the response is 200 then it sets the `props` .. If it fails, it should redirect the user to the login page. but whenever i hit the page it shows the 404 page, which means it seems to be entering into the `catch` part of the try block ... I have tested the api endpoint with the token and it works perfectly, its just when i use it as below it fails;

```
import React from 'react'

import httpRequest from '@/lib/httpRequest'
import { getCookie } from '@/lib/session'

const Settings = ({ dashboardUser }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Protected Page</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
    try {
        const resDashboardUser = await httpRequest.get({
            url: '/api/user',
            token: getCookie('token', req)
        })

        if (resDashboardUser.status === 200) {
            return {
                props: {
                    dashboardUser: resDashboardUser.data
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (error?.response?.status === 401) {
            return {
                redirect: {
                    destination: '/login',
                    permanent: false
                }
            }
        }

        return {
            notFound: true
        }
    }
}

export default Settings
```

The following is the `get` function of the `httpRequest`

```
get: ({ baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL, url, token, params }) => {
    return axios({
        timeout: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_TIMEOUT,
        method: 'get',
        baseURL: baseUrl,
        url: url,
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token || ''
        },
        params: params
    });
},
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error I am seeing is as follows;

```
Promise { <pending> }
error - unhandledRejection: AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1138:16) {
  port: 80,
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  syscall: 'connect',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: -111,
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: '30000',
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer 8|jcL6IL08oMqKET2r0Skhjx1Dw02UTeToNukQpqm4',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.27.2'
    },
    method: 'get',
    baseURL: 'http://localhost',
    url: '/api/user',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      constructed: true,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError],
      socket: [Array]
    },
    _eventsCount: 3,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      protocol: 'http:',
      path: '/api/user',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: 'localhost',
      port: null,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/api/user'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'GET /api/user HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Bearer 8|jcL6IL08oMqKET2r0Skhjx1Dw02UTeToNukQpqm4\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.27.2\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: {},
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/api/user',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    _currentUrl: 'http://localhost/api/user',
    _timeout: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry ... Its a header

Comment: Currently developing both on localhost ... not a CORS issue as the login and register pages work perfectly

Comment: can you try to log the error to the console in the first line of the catch block before any IF condition ?

Comment: and please double check of the baseURL inside the request, maybe it contains "/api" and as i see here you are also sending "/api" in the subURL (url parameter)

Comment: @ShadiAmr ... Im finding that i cant actually console log anything inside the `getServerSideProps` ... I guess thats becuase its doing it before rendering which im finding really frustrating

The baseURL works fine, i have tested the code outside of the `getServerSideProps` and there isnt any problems .. I cant figure it out

Comment: It seems as though its just returning the `notFound: true` straight away as its showing a 404 when i go to that page .... Its strange

Comment: YES you can see the logs even inside getServerSideProps , but not in the browser , in terminal you 'll see it

Comment: And since it's a 404 , so it's mostly doesn't recognize the endpoint at all

Comment: so now just to ensure that everything is fine with the request , can you do this :
`axions.get(${baseURL}/${url}, { headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token || ''
        } });`
instead ?

Comment: Oh, it is logging to the terminal, i didnt know that .... If i `console.log(error)` it spits out a LOT of data

Comment: `AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80`

Comment: In my .env.local i have `NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost` which is being used in the httpRequest get function

Comment: i would like to see the whole error not only this line maybe i can then find some reference

Comment: @ShadiAmr I have updated the question with the error i am seeing in the console

Comment: ok did you try to add await here : `return await axios({ ...` and don't forget to add async to the method : `get: async ({ baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL, url, token, params }) => {`

Comment: What port is the Laravel API running on locally?

Comment: From what I can see you trying to get a request to plain `localhost/api./user`
So your fix should be to update the NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:[laravelPort]

Cause you do not have anything running on port `80` ;]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making an http request from `getServerSideProps` to an `api` route, move the code from `api/users` to `getServerSideProps`. Do the server-side work in `getServerSideProps`.

`getServerSideProps` is server-side code even though it is in a client-side file. When you call a server-side route (e.g., `api/users`) from `getServerSideProps` or other static functions, it doesn't work.

The example says [from external API](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#using-getserversideprops-to-fetch-data-at-request-time). Here is [another answer about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65760948/19829260).

So let me know how that goes.

Meanwhile . . .

A few notes that might be irrelevant after you refactor, if you're not sending an http request to get the cookie. But worth mentioning anyway.

When making http requests in NextJS, [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) is easier than `httpRequest`, assuming it works for your situation.

When sending https requests, try adding `async / await` to handle `Promises` that `axios` or `fetch` or `httpRequest` returns.

Here is an example.

```
get: async ({ baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL, url, token, params }) => {
    return await axios({
        timeout: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_TIMEOUT,
        method: 'get',
        baseURL: baseUrl,
        url: url,
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token || ''
        },
        params: params
    });
},
```

When you see `Promise { <pending> }`, that means you need to handle the `Promise` to get the actual data you want. A `Promise` is just a placeholder for a value that doesn't exist when the page loads. The value doesn't exist at load time because `axios` has to request and receive it.

When you see `error - unhandledRejection: AxiosError:`, that suggests maybe the error is because the code doesn't handle the `Promise`.

You can handle `Promises` using `async / await` or `.then()`. Which one to use is typically driven by the situation and your preference. Here, `async / await` makes sense.

However, for your situation, I think the http request is problematic because of how `getServerSideProps` and `api` routes don't work together. Good luck!!

Comment: Hey, thank you for the suggestion, but its still doing the same thing

Comment: No problem. I updated my answer. Sorry I didn't see the problem sooner. I think I got distracted with the httpRequest because I'm not used to seeing that. I'm more used to fetch. Anyway, I think my edited answer will get you past this error.

Comment: Are you talking about moving the actual get method from the `httpRequest.js` file and move it into the `getServerSideProps` ?

Comment: Move the code you have in api/users into getServerSideProps.

Comment: `api/users` is the backend route im calling ... Its not part of the frontend

Comment: getServerSideProps can’t call internal backend routes. So what you do is move the code from the backend route into getServerSideProps. Then you don’t need to call the route. getServerSideProps is backend code. But it lives in a client-side file.

Answer (score 0):

When you make request in `getServerSideProps`, you have to pass full url. when you are on server, you have no access to `host`. `next-absolute-url` package will get us the host

```
import absoluteUrl from 'next-absolute-url'

export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
const { origin } = absoluteUrl(req);

try {
    const resDashboardUser = await httpRequest.get({
        url: `${origin}/api/user`,
        token: getCookie('token', req)
    })
.....
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to work either ... I have hardcoded `http://localhost/api/user` into the URL and still 404

Comment: is it same error? can you send a request with the postman to that url

Comment: Using postman returns the correct data for that endpoint, as shown in the first code block of my questions

Comment: then maybe you are not passing the correct token or headers.  check if `getToken` retruns valid token.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the port where the Laravel API is running on in the `NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL` value.

Assuming the Laravel API is running on port `8080` you should update the environment variable to the following.

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:8080
```