# Next-Auth: Cannot get Access Token with getToken() inside API middleware inside getServerSideProps() [ Undefined Error ]

Tags: reactjs, next.js, access-token, next-auth

my `access_token` from `const access_token = await getToken({ req, secret })` always returns `undefined` inside the `next-js` `API Middleware` which is called by `await axios.get()` inside `getServerSideProps()`, is this normal?

I can get the `accessToken` inside `getServerSideProps()` and pass it as parameter over to the `API Middleware`page but not getting the `accessToken` directly inside the `API Middleware`page

`pages/user.js` page:

```
function User({user_data, request_params}) {
   ....
}

export default User;


export async function getServerSideProps( context ) {

    const user_data = await fetchUserData( context.query );

    return {
        props: {
            user_data: user_data,
            request_params: context.query
        }
    }

}


async function fetchUserData( params ) {

    // Create AJAX URL
    const ajax_url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/user/1/info';

    let result;

    await axios.get(ajax_url)
        .then(response => {

            result = response.data;

        }).catch((error) => {

            // Error
            if (error.response) {
                // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
                // that falls out of the range of 2xx
                console.log('Error.response > Data: ', error.response.data);
                console.log('Error.response > Status: ', error.response.status);
                console.log('Error.response > Headers: ', error.response.headers);

            } else if (error.request) {
                // The request was made but no response was received
                // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the
                // browser and an instance of
                // http.ClientRequest in node.js
                console.log('Error.request: ', error.request);

            } else {
                // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                console.log('Error: ', error.message);
            }
            console.log('Unknown Error: ', error.config);

        });

    return result;

}
```

`api/user/[user]/info.js` page:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";

const secret = process.env.SECRET

export default async (req, res) => {

    // Get Access Token [ undefined ]
    const access_token = await getToken({
        req: req,
        secret: secret,
    })

    console.log('access token?: ' + access_token.accessToken); // undefined

    // Config
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'authorization': `Bearer ${access_token.accessToken}`,
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
            'Expires': '0',
        }
    };

    const ajax_url = 'http://localhost/actualwebsite/public/api/v1/user/' + req.query.user + '/' + 'info';

    await axios.get(ajax_url, config)
        .then(response => {

            res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
            res.setHeader('Expires', '0');
            res.status(200).json(response.data);

        }).catch((error) => {

            // Error
            if (error.response) {
                // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
                // that falls out of the range of 2xx
                console.log('Api > Error.response > Data: ', error.response.data);
                console.log('Api > Error.response > Status: ', error.response.status);
                console.log('Api > Error.response > Headers: ', error.response.headers);

            } else if (error.request) {
                // The request was made but no response was received
                // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the
                // browser and an instance of
                // http.ClientRequest in node.js
                console.log('Api > Error.request: ', error.request);

            } else {
                // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                console.log('Api > Error: ', error.message);
            }
            console.log('Api > Unknown Error: ', error.config);

        });

}
```

Comment: maybe your session has expired

Comment: its not, because I can still access token in `getServerSideProps()` and other places outside of the middleware API

Comment: You shouldn't fetch data from an internal API route inside `getServerSideProps`. Instead use the logic that's in your API route directly in `getServerSideProps`. See [Internal API fetch with getServerSideProps? (Next.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752932/internal-api-fetch-with-getserversideprops-next-js).