# Next.js: Access cookies in API route

Tags: javascript, authentication, http, cookies, next.js

I'm developing a To-Do app with authentication, using Next.js 12, Mongoose and JWT.

The user logs in and gets a cookie called `userAuthToken` which has: username, password and user id.

When an authenticated user creates a new task, a `POST` request ( with the task's data ) is sent to `src/pages/api/tasks/index.js` , where the authentication is checked and the new task is assigned to the user's document in MongoDB ( this part is not working yet ).

In `src/pages/api/tasks/index.js` ( where tasks are sent from client ), i am trying to access cookies in order to check authentication like so:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { method, body, cookies } = req;

  const { userAuthToken } = cookies;

  console.log({ cookies });
  console.log({ userAuthToken });

``// ...
}I
```

In `src/pages/tasks/index.js` i use `getServerSideProps` to fetch tasks from `src/pages/api/tasks`:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TASKS_API_URL; // localhost:3000/api/tasks
  const response = await fetch(URL);
  const tasks = await response.json();

  return {
    props: {
      tasks: tasks.error ? [] : tasks
    }
  };
}
```

Now: When i enter to `localhost:3000/tasks`, in backend terminal is shown:

[image]

( cookies not defined )

But, when i enter to `localhost:3000/api/tasks`  the backend terminal shows:

[image]

( cookies defined )

Neither HTTP-only nor '*public'* cookies are logged in console when i enter to client tasks route ( `localhost:3000/tasks` ),  but when i enter to API route ( `localhost:3000/api/tasks` ) they are logged in backend console normally.

Also, i have a `middleware.js`  in `src`, but i tried removing it and there wasn't difference:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { jwtVerify } from "jose";

export async function middleware(req) {
  const { cookies, url } = req;

  const authToken = cookies.get("userAuthToken");

  if (authToken === undefined) {
    const urlToRedirect = new URL("/login", url);

    return NextResponse.redirect(urlToRedirect);
  }

  try {
    await jwtVerify(authToken, new TextEncoder().encode("secret"));

    return NextResponse.next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);

    const urlToRedirect = new URL("/login", url);
    return NextResponse.redirect(urlToRedirect);
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/tasks/:path*", "/dashboard"]
};
```

This middleware is only executed in `/tasks/` and `/dashboard`. Logs to the console from here are always shown correctly.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Do not fetch data from internal API routes in `getServerSideProps`. Instead use the logic in the API route directly. See [Internal API fetch with getServerSideProps? (Next.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752932/internal-api-fetch-with-getserversideprops-next-js).

Comment: Hello back. The error was that i wasn't sending cookies in the request headers from `getServerSideProps()`