# TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported on strapi app deployed on Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, build, next.js, strapi

I have a nextjs app with a strapi api deployed with heroku and the frontend with firebase. I use an environnement variable to fetch my api. It worked well in localhost but not with Heroku. I get the error: Only absolute URLs are supported**

I tried to hardcode my api URL, but I guess this is not the very best solution

Does someone ever meet that kind of problem ?

```
> Build error occurred
TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
    at getNodeRequestOptions (/Users/mac/Documents/Website/strapi/strapi-starter/strapi-starter-next-ecommerce/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/node-fetch/index.js:1:64341)
    at /Users/mac/Documents/Website/strapi/strapi-starter/strapi-starter-next-ecommerce/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/node-fetch/index.js:1:65715
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at fetch (/Users/mac/Documents/Website/strapi/strapi-starter/strapi-starter-next-ecommerce/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/node-fetch/index.js:1:65650)
    at fetchAPI (/Users/mac/Documents/Website/strapi/strapi-starter/strapi-starter-next-ecommerce/frontend/.next/server/pages/books/[name].js:7040:26)
    at getProducts (/Users/mac/Documents/Website/strapi/strapi-starter/strapi-starter-next-ecommerce/frontend/.next/server/pages/books/[name].js:7053:26)
    at getStaticPaths (/Users/mac/Documents/Website/strapi/strapi-starter/strapi-starter-next-ecommerce/frontend/.next/server/pages/books/[name].js:6997:60)
    at buildStaticPaths (/Users/mac/Documents/Website/strapi/strapi-starter/strapi-starter-next-ecommerce/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:17:86)
    at Object.isPageStatic (/Users/mac/Documents/Website/strapi/strapi-starter/strapi-starter-next-ecommerce/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:24:555)
    at execFunction (/Users/mac/Documents/Website/strapi/strapi-starter/strapi-starter-next-ecommerce/frontend/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:155:17) {
  type: 'TypeError'
}
```

api.js

```
export function getStrapiURL(path) {
  return `https://intense-beyond-59367.herokuapp.com${path}`;
}

// Helper to make GET requests to Strapi
export async function fetchAPI(path) {
  const requestUrl = getStrapiURL(path);
  const response = await fetch(requestUrl);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

export async function getCategories() {
  const categories = await fetchAPI("/categories");
  return categories;
}

export async function getCategory(slug) {
  const categories = await fetchAPI(`/categories?slug=${slug}`);
  return categories?.[0];
}

export async function getProducts() {
  const products = await fetchAPI("/books");
  return products;
}

export async function getProduct(name) {
  const products = await fetchAPI(`/books?name=${name}`);
  return products?.[0];
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js - Error: only absolute urls are supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342226/next-js-error-only-absolute-urls-are-supported)

Comment: I tried with hardcoded URL and it worked, but it's not ideal. Environnement variables are very usefull. I would like to be able to use it