# "Only absolute URLs are supported" When fetch webhooks Nextjs

Tags: environment-variables, fetch, next.js, webhooks

Im trying to fetch an webhooks url using Environment Variables.
here is my code

```
      const url = process.env.WEBHOOK_URL;
      const response = await fetch(
        `${url}` ,
        {
          body: JSON.stringify({
            name,
            email,
            message,
          }),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          method: 'POST'
        }
      );
```

But the error show up "Only absolute URLs are supported"
please help! Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js - Error: only absolute urls are supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342226/next-js-error-only-absolute-urls-are-supported)